# Maven repository url access

Tags: maven, maven-3, pom.xml

I would like to get the URL of the maven repository being used by the project in the pom.xml.

I tried the suggestion as described at [Maven: Get repository URL of a dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39506740/maven-get-repository-url-of-a-dependency)
but wasn't successful at getting the URL.
On further exploration I found ${project.pluginRepositories} listing the list of the repository. However, I wasn't able to extract the URL from the pluginRepositories list.

```
echo of ${project.pluginRepositories} prints [id = 'maven-releases', id = 'central'].
```

I'm looking for a way to extract "central" repository URL.

Comment: Why not use the standard maven central url?

Comment: We have local mirrors & some internal artifacts, hence I wanted to use config as defined in the settings.xml

Comment: Ok, you confuse me. Above you are talking about repositories from a POM, then you talk about pluginRepositories, now you speak about config from the settings.xml. What exactly do you want to find out? Maybe it is easier if you explain some background because maybe there is already a solution for your original problem that is less complicated.

Comment: Maybe I'm not able to clearly convey my use case. I want to have a utility to download & configure some files (part of internal maven/artifactory/external URL). So I want to pass the repo URL when that utility is integrated to maven, since I don't want to be always editable, I want to read from the available configuration & pass to utility. Hence I was trying to access  project.pluginRepositories in pom.

Answer (score 0):

I have following thoughts in this context:

1) Just run command `mvn --version`. Go to maven installation directory and view the content of `settings.xml` file under `conf` folder. It should tell you which maven central repository is being used. It could be possible that there is no specific repository listed there. If that is the case then either default central repository is being used or it will be determined from content of `pom.xml` file of maven module.

2) If `settings.xml` file does not have any specific repository mentioned then go to maven module and check `effective-pom`. It should tell you which maven central repository is being used. You might get similar to following tags in your `effective-pom` file

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>Central Repository</name>
      <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
```

Following links should also help you further:

http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.6.0/maven-model-builder/#Model_Interpolation
http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.6.0/maven-settings/settings.html

Please try using `${settings.repositories}` which will return `List<Repository>`

Comment: Do you know how can I loop through the list of values from ${settings.repositories} to get each repo URL. Within pom.xml